# If / else on powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am currently learning how to use powershell and was wondering how would you make a simple process like this for example.

> If the time is between 9am and 12pm then write to 'Get coffee' else
>   write nothing.

Comment: In the powershell console type: Get-Help about_if

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631564/powershell-how-to-get-if-else-construct-right

Comment: Hi @lolbol, welcome to stack overflow you will notice from the short responses, that people expect questions to show what you have tried, so at least we can all see some effort put in.  The more you put into the question, the more you will get out.

Comment: I usually refer people to whathaveyoutried dot com  :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

```
if ((9,10,11) -contains (get-date).Hour) { "get coffee" }

if ((get-date).hour -ge 9 -and (get-date).hour -le 11) { "get coffee" }

if (((get-date -hour 12 -min 0 -sec 0) - (get-date)).hours -in 0..2) { ... }
```

This might be a fun community wiki question.

Comment: I don't think this question needs any more answers, but here is another option:  if((Get-Date).Hour -match '9|10|11|12'){'Get-Coffee'}

Answer (score 1):

This is about as short as I can get it...

```
if(Get-Date | ? {($_.hour -ge 9) -and ($_.hour -le 12)}){"get coffee"}
```

Comment: Technically that will evaluate true all the way up to 12.59. You really want -le 11, to go to 11.59.

Comment: Well, it complies to exactly what the OP stated as the problem definition. There is some ambiguity in the problem definition though since the 9-12 could be minutes or hours.

Comment: Read the question again... hahahaha, sorry. It needed clarification.

Comment: this is not the stack exchange site [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), shortening code through the use of abbreviated aliases and lack of formatting is usually not simpler for beginners as the OP actually asked for.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents (using .net):

```
[datetime]$now = [datetime]::now.Tostring("T",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture )
$low = [datetime] "09:00:00 am"
$hi = [datetime] "12:00:00 pm"
if ( $now -ge $low -and $now -le $hi  ) { "Coffee Time!" } else {"Work!"}
```